# Ubuntu 20.04 on W10 PC via Oracle VirtualBox 6.1 cant use USB's of host

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-10

Retired firefighter here dipping his toe into the Ubuntu pool. Trying to get Ubuntu 20 to cooperate with my PC

My PC is a Windows 10 1909 / i7_8700k 6 core / ROG Strix Z370-E GAMING MB / Ubuntu 20.04 running on VirtualBox 6.1

When setting up Ubuntu in VirtualBox, working through the menu I came to USB. There was only one option to choose from at 'Enable USB Controller' and it was USB 1.1 which wasn't very helpful.

I have installed a few different OS's in VirtualBox and always that field gave me a choice of 1.1, 2.1 and 3 but this installation for whatever reason only 1.1 was offered. It didn't give me a workable USB

While running Ubuntu 20 on VB I attempted to access one of the USB 3 ports on the front of my PC and a message popped up at the top of the screen and before I could read it the PC BSOD'd.

After a reboot, I went to the VB settings wanting to maybe adjust the configuration and lo and behold there was an additional option of 3.1, so I ticked the box but couldn't restart because it indicated that I needed to install an Oracle VM VirtualBox extension pack. A what?

I'm getting confused. So there are three separate pieces to make this thing work on a Windows machine? The VirtualBox itself, Guest Additions and now an "extension pack", is that right?

I'm so close to making this thing work. Please help a newb who is floundering.

Answer (score 1):

I see that yes indeed Extension Packs are something different than Guest Additions.

I found this tutorial helpful:
https://linuxconfig.org/virtualbox-extension-pack-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Now Ive got USB 3 working while Im in Ubuntu... fingers crossed it stays that way